Rule 2 in Pearl's do calculus

Rule 2 in Pearl's do calculus states that if $Y\perp_{G_{\bar T, \underline Z}}Z|T, W$, then $P(y|do(t), do(z), w) = P(y|do(t), z, w)$. Is the following DAG $G$ a counterexample? How to understand this rule?

It would appear that $Z$ is also an empty set, which makes the example a bit confusing, "confounded", even (pun intended, of course). Or what is your $Z$ for this example?

In this example, $Z$ is not an empty set. You may think of $Z$ as a random variable as shown in the DAG. Here $G_{\bar T, \underline Z}$ means the graph $G$ where all the outgoing edges from $Z$ are deleted (so we no longer have $Z\rightarrow M$).

Oh, weird. I must have missed seeing Z yesterday. Just ignore me!

I do not see a counterexample. What occurs is that the $do$-calculus, developed by Dr. Judea Pearl, may yield distributions that do not directly represent valid causal contrasts. This is because they might be conditioned on post-treatment variables, leading to different subpopulations being compared against.
Given that there is no variable $T$ in your graph $G$, rule 2 would be expressed as $Y\perp Z\mid W$ in $G_{\underline{Z}}$. This rule is indeed met here, as removing all arrows leaving $Z$ results in it being completely disconnected from all other variables, particularly $Y$, even when conditioned on $W$ (which induces dependence between $M$ and $Y$ due to conditioning on collider). Since the rule holds, one has $p(y\mid\text{do}(z),w)=p(y\mid z,w)$
This represents the distribution of $Y$ among the units that received treatment value $z$ and achieved a $W$-value of $w$. However, this distribution cannot be directly used to compute a valid causal contrast, because altering the value of $z$ would also alter the value of $w$, as $W$ is a descendant of $Z$. In other words, with a binary treatment, the distributions $Q_1=p(y\mid z=1,w)$ and $Q_0=p(y\mid z=0,w)$ do not describe the same units. Those achieving $w$ under $z=1$ might differ from those achieving it under $z=0$. Therefore, the shift from $Q_1$ to $Q_0$ is not solely due to treatment but also due to comparing different units.
Thus, while the $do$-calculus provides the correct result, $p(y\mid\text{do}(z),w)=p(y\mid z,w)$, it answers the wrong question. A valid causal comparison would be expressed in counterfactual notation, as $p(y_z\mid w)$ instead of $p(y\mid\text{do}(z),w)$. Comparing $Q_1'=p(y_1\mid w)$ to $Q_0'=p(y_0\mid w)$ is valid, as the units are the same: all those achieving $W=w$, regardless of whether they were treated ($z=1$) or control ($z=0$). Pearl refers to $p(y_z\mid w)$ as a unit-specific effect due to this distinction.
I recommend you to read his paper on this topic:

Judea Pearl. Conditioning on post-treatment variables. Journal of Causal Inference, 3(1):131–137, 2015. doi:10.1515/jci-2015-0005. URL https://doi.org/10.1515/jci-2015-0005.

